# How to keeping start datastax service on windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed Cassandra 3.3.0 on windows server 2012 r2 properly and without any error.despite on I set manual for stop/start datastaxs service on "services.msc", it goes to stop by windows server. My question is: "What should I do to keeping start datastaxs service all the time without any stopping?"

Comment: What does your system.log say?  Perhaps there is a reason it keeps stopping on you.  Basically, without establishing *why* it keeps stopping, talking about how to automatically restart it is a little premature.

Comment: @Aaron 8 how I can find "system.log"? you mean ../data/commitlog folder?

Comment: May be it is for minimum RAM requirements? My pcs RAM is: 4 GB (3.87 usable).

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears for minimum RAM requirements on PC. When I move on another one with 8 GB ram, all work correctly.